# Defining complicated facts - Einsteins Zebra

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I am trying to figure out the right fact representation of complicated relations in `Prolog`.

There are 6 tents in 2 lines represented as:

```
tent(color, orientation, place, mans name, womans name, surename, car)
```

1. I need to write down a fact saying

> The man named Peter is in the
>       tent NOT in front of Ian's tent

.

2. Can I (and how) write down the fact saying

> Peter's wife name is
>           not Ann?

EDIT:

Oh, I was not really clear in defining the "In front of". In this case it is NOT an ordinal thing, I'll try to show you:

```
FOREST  tent1  tent2  tent3  RIVER
FOREST  tent4  tent5  tent6  RIVER
```

In the meaning that tent1 is in front of tent4. And then the tent1 has orientation "NORTH" and position "FOREST". The tent that is NOT IN FRONT OF IT would be tent5(orientation "SOUTH", position "MIDDLE").

The thing with dif(Wife, 'Ann') works just fine, thank you for that.

I consulted this with the professor and the we agreed on that for this assignment I really do not need a fact negation, the goal was to do the right decision and ignore the unneccessary facts.

Thanks for helping me out, anyways.

Comment: how about letting Prolog [discover it by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzebra-puzzle%5D+user%3A849891+attr)?

Comment: I don't understand the "in front of" still :-( so is "to the south of" the same as "in front of"? Isn't any tent that is not "in front of" then "not in front of"? So, in your example, it could be tent2, tent3, tent5, or tent6?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the third argument, "place", is an ordinal, and "X in front of Y" means that X < Y, and "not in front" is then X > Y, then the query for the first rule would be:

```
tent(_, _, Place_Peter, 'Peter', _, _, _),
tent(_, _, Place_Ian, 'Ian', _, _, _),
Place_Peter > Place_Ian
```

But of course it could also be that "X is the place not in front of Y" means that

```
succ(Y0, Y),
X =\= Y0
```

I am not sure.

The second one would be:

```
tent(_, _, _, 'Peter', Wife, _, _),
dif(Wife, 'Ann')
```

But note that these are not facts, those are queries that will have (or not have) a solution, and will either succeed or fail, based on the contents of the table `tent/7`.

In both cases I am making some assumptions about the data types of the different columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy with this tent predicate of arity 7.

How about this skeleton code. It took me a bit to recover lost Prolog knowledge. I'm using "negation as failure" to make sure the constraints are followed. It works in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/).

This might be easier to encode in a Prolog-like language that is made for constraint satisfaction ([ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/) or [ASP/Potassco](https://potassco.org/) maybe? I have never tried to do that though.)

Writing this, it turns out that

- The fun thing with Prolog is that you never really know whether the solution you get is what you actually want.
- Solution too short, too large, won't return, gives false only. Argh!
- You don't need complex datastructures ... but you need assertions to check intermediate, partial solutions.
- One gets the feeling that one is way, way slower than when coding in imperative language, but this not really true. There are more inferences to handle when looking a single line, which would be equivalent to a paragraph of confusing boredom in an imperative language.

So:

```
% Create tents and indicate their positions, too. These are basically "tent names"
% in the form of a literal where the name carries the x and y position. 
% We won't need this but "in front of" means: in_front_of(tent(X,1),tent(X,2)).

tent(1,1). 
tent(2,1).
tent(3,1).
tent(1,2).
tent(2,2).
tent(3,2).

% Create colors (just as an example)

color(blue).
color(red).
color(green).
color(white).
color(black).
color(mauve).

% Create cars (just as an example)

car(mazda).
car(ford).
car(renault).
car(tesla).
car(skoda).
car(unimog).

% Create surnames (just as an example)

surname(skywalker).
surname(olsndot).
surname(oneagle).

% Create names (just as an example) and give the traditional sex

name(peter,male).
name(marvin,male).
name(ian,male).
name(sheila,female).
name(mary,female).
name(ann,female).

% Give traditional family pair. male is first element in pair.

pair(Nm,Nf,Sn) :- name(Nm,male),name(Nf,female),surname(Sn).

% Our logic universe is now filled with floating stuff: tents, colors, cars, names.
% A "solution" consists in linking these together into a consistent whole respecting
% all the constraints given by the "zebra puzzle"

% A "solution" is a data structure like any other. We choose to have a big list with
% literals. Every literal expresses an assignment between a tent and an attribute:
% 
%   attribute_nameΔ(tent_x,tent_y,attribute_value) 
%   
% Other representations are possible. (Why the "Δ"? Because I like it!)

% We need a list of all tents over which to recurse/induct when generating a "solution".
% ... bagof provides!
% This could possibly be done by directly backtracking over the tent/2 predicate.

all_tents(LTs) :- bagof(tent(X,Y), tent(X,Y), LTs).

% We need a list of all pairs over which to recurse/induct when generating a "solution".
% ... bagof provides!
% This could possibly be done by directly backtracking over the pair/2 predicate.

all_pairs(Ps) :- bagof(pair(Nm,Nf,Sn), pair(Nm,Nf,Sn), Ps). 

% Select possible assignments of "color<->tent", adding the possible assignments to
% an existing list of selected assignments.
%
% assign_colors(List-of-Tents-to-recurse-over,List-with-Assignments(In),List-with-more-Assignments(Out)).

assign_colors([],Bounce,Bounce).
assign_colors([tent(X,Y)|Ts], Acc, Out) :- 
    color(Co),
    \+is_color_used(Acc,Co),
    assign_colors(Ts, [colorΔ(X,Y,Co)|Acc], Out).

is_color_used([colorΔ(_,_,Co)|_],Co) :- !.  % cut to make this deterministic
is_color_used([_|R],Co) :- is_color_used(R,Co).

% Select possible assignment of "car<->tent", adding the possible assignments to
% an existing list of selected assignments.
%
% assign_cars(List-of-Tents-to-recurse-over,List-with-Assignments(In),List-with-more-Assignments(Out)).

assign_cars([],Bounce,Bounce).
assign_cars([tent(X,Y)|Ts], Acc, Out) :-
    car(Ca),
    \+is_car_used(Acc,Ca),
    assign_cars(Ts, [carΔ(X,Y,Ca)|Acc], Out).

is_car_used([carΔ(_,_,Ca)|_],Ca) :- !.  % cut to make this deterministic
is_car_used([_|R],Ca) :- is_car_used(R,Ca).

% Select possible assignment of "name<->tent", adding the possible assignments to
% an existing list of selected assignments.
% 
% In this case, we have to check additional constraints when choosing a possible assignment: 
% 
% 1) A name may only be used once
% 2) Ian and Peter's are not in front of each other
% 
% assign_names(List-of-Tents-to-recurse-over,List-with-Assignments(In),List-with-more-Assignments(Out)).

assign_names([],Bounce,Bounce).
assign_names([tent(X,Y)|Ts], Acc, Out) :-
    name(Na,_),
    \+is_name_used(Acc,Na),
    \+is_ian_in_front_of_peter([nameΔ(X,Y,Na)|Acc]),
    assign_names(Ts, [nameΔ(X,Y,Na)|Acc], Out).

is_name_used([nameΔ(_,_,Na)|_],Na) :- !.  % cut to make this deterministic
is_name_used([_|R],Na) :- is_name_used(R,Na).

is_ian_in_front_of_peter(S) :- 
    pick_name(S,nameΔ(X,_,_),peter),
    pick_name(S,nameΔ(X,_,_),ian),
    write("IAN vs PETER confirmed!\n").

pick_name([nameΔ(X,Y,Name)|_],nameΔ(X,Y,Name),Name).
pick_name([_|R],Found,Name) :- pick_name(R,Found,Name).

% Select possible pairs, adding the possible pairs to an existing list of selected pairs (the same
% as the list of selected assignments). The nature of this selection is **different than the two
% others** as we backtrack over the list of pairs, instead of just recursing over it. Hence,
% three clauses^and a verification that we have 3 pairs in the end.
% 
% In this case, we have to check additional constraints when choosing a possible assignment: 
% 
% 1) Peter's wife name is not Ann
%
% assign_pairs(List-of-Pairs-to-recurse-over,List-with-Assignments(In),List-with-more-Assignments(Out)).

assign_pairs([],Bounce,Bounce) :- count_pairs(Bounce,3). % hardcoded number of surnames; we need 3 pairs!
assign_pairs([pair(Nm,Nf,Sn)|Ps], Acc, Out) :-
    \+is_any_name_already_paired(Acc,Nm,Nf,Sn),
    \+is_peter_married_ann([pairΔ(Nm,Nf,Sn)|Acc]),
    assign_pairs(Ps, [pairΔ(Nm,Nf,Sn)|Acc], Out).
assign_pairs([_|Ps], Acc, Out) :- assign_pairs(Ps, Acc, Out).

is_any_name_already_paired([pairΔ(N,_,_)|_],N,_,_) :- !. % cut to make this deterministic
is_any_name_already_paired([pairΔ(_,N,_)|_],_,N,_) :- !. % cut to make this deterministic
is_any_name_already_paired([pairΔ(_,_,S)|_],_,_,S) :- !. % cut to make this deterministic
is_any_name_already_paired([_|R],Nm,Nf,Sn) :- is_any_name_already_paired(R,Nm,Nf,Sn).

count_pairs([],0).
count_pairs([pairΔ(_,_,_)|R],C) :- !,count_pairs(R,C2), C is C2+1. % red cut
count_pairs([_|R],C) :- count_pairs(R,C).

% this would be more advantageously done by eliminating that pair in the list of
% possible pairs; but leave it here to make the solution less "a bag of special cases"

is_peter_married_ann([pairΔ(peter,ann,_)|_]) :- !. % cut to make this deterministic
is_peter_married_ann([_|R]) :- is_peter_married_ann(R).

% Find a consistent solution by adding assignements for the various attributes
% while checking constraints

solution(SOut) :- 
    all_tents(Tents),
    all_pairs(Pairs),
    assign_colors(Tents,[],S1),
    assign_cars(Tents,S1,S2),
    assign_names(Tents,S2,S3),
    assign_pairs(Pairs,S3,SOut).
```

Run it

```
?- solution(SOut).

SOut = [pairΔ(ian, ann, oneagle), pairΔ(marvin, mary, olsndot), 
pairΔ(peter, sheila, skywalker), nameΔ(3, 2, ann), nameΔ(2, 2, mary),
nameΔ(1, 2, sheila), nameΔ(3, 1, ian), nameΔ(2, 1, marvin),
nameΔ(1, 1, peter), carΔ(3, 2, unimog), carΔ(2, 2, skoda), 
carΔ(1, 2, tesla), carΔ(3, 1, renault), carΔ(2, 1, ford), 
carΔ(1, 1, mazda), colorΔ(3, 2, mauve), colorΔ(2, 2, black), 
colorΔ(1, 2, white), colorΔ(3, 1, green), colorΔ(2, 1, red), 
colorΔ(1, 1, blue)]
```